# Installing Orange Data Mining Package from GitHub

Tags: pip, package, orange

I am familiar with the normal way to install packages natively though Orange's add-ons tab:

click options -> add-ons -> then install various packages.

**My question though is:** How do I install packages for Orange where the package is available on GitHub. I imagine I need to use pip- install to get it on my system. Is this advisable to do through pip vs a system like Anaconda in case the package interferes with something else? If it is on GitHub can I also install the package from Anaconda?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited: the correct answer is

1. pip install

Most add-ons can be installed with a simple

```
pip install orange3-imageanalytics
```

command. I have not seen issues with Anaconda so far. There are some packages available on conda, as well, for example

```
conda install orange3-text
```

This you have to do in your Orange environment. If you installed Orange on Windows, there should be Orange Command Prompt, where you can access this.

2. dev version from Github

Clone the package from Github locally. Then cd into the folder and run pip install.

```
git clone https://github.com/biolab/orange3-text.git
cd orange3-text
pip install -e .
```

This will run pip for all requirements of the package.

Comment: I think this answer was for a different question.